# sharp.js with node on cloud function - return text/html instead of an Image

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, sharp

In my local i manage to get the image as it should to the user browser or via postman

but in the real firebase cloud function api i got a text/html buffer text instead of an image

how can i fix it to make sure only image will return ?

i have the following code:

```
getSharp(){
  const res = await axiosInstance.request({ url: imageUrl, responseType: 'stream' });
   return res.data.pipe(sharp()) as Sharp;
}


const sharp = getSharp()
  const buffer = await sharp
        .resize({ width: imageWidth })
        .jpeg({
          quality: 80,
        })
        .toBuffer();


       response.status(200).write(buffer, () => response.end())
```